# This webpage has a redirect loop - PHP Login

Tags: php, authentication

I'm trying out a login page example in php. I get the error: **This webpage has a redirect loop**
Details say: Error code: ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Here's my code:

**index.php**

```
<?php
include('login.php'); // Includes Login Script

if(isset($_SESSION['login_user'])){
header("location: profile.php");
}
?>


                <form action="" method="post">
                <label>UserName :</label>
                <input id="name" name="username" placeholder="username" type="text">
                <label>Password :</label>
                <input id="password" name="password" placeholder="**********" type="password">
                <input name="submit" type="submit" value=" Login ">
                <span><?php echo $error; ?></span>
            </form>
```

**login.php**

```
<?php
session_start(); 
$error=''; 

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    if (empty($_POST['username']) || empty($_POST['password'])) {
        $error = "Username or Password is invalid";
    }
    else
    {

        $username=$_POST['username'];
        $password=$_POST['password'];

        $connection = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");

        $username = stripslashes($username);
        $password = stripslashes($password);
        $username = mysql_real_escape_string($username);
        $password = mysql_real_escape_string($password);

        $db = mysql_select_db("rjtest", $connection);

        $query = mysql_query("select * from login where myPassword='$password' AND myUserName='$username'", $connection);
        $rows = mysql_num_rows($query);
        if ($rows == 1) {
            $_SESSION['login_user']=$username;
            header("location: profile.php"); 
        } else {
            $error = "Username or Password is invalid";
        }
    }
}
?>
```

**profile.php**

```
<?php
include('session.php');
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Your Home Page</title>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="profile">
<b id="welcome">Welcome : <i><?php echo $login_session; ?></i></b>
<b id="logout"><a href="logout.php">Log Out</a></b>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**session.php**

```
<?php

$connection = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");

$db = mysql_select_db("rjtest", $connection);
session_start();

$user_check=$_SESSION['login_user'];

$ses_sql=mysql_query("select myUsername from login where myUsername='$user_check'", $connection);
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($ses_sql);
$login_session =$row['username'];
if(!isset($login_session)){

header('Location: index.php'); 
}
?>
```

And **logout.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
if(session_destroy())
{
header("Location: index.php");
}
?>
```

I can't seem figure out why. The site where I got this code is now inactive, so that's why Im asking this here. Hope you guys could help me out. Sorry for the long post though.

Comment: does the profile.php page include the session_start()?

Comment: oh yes it does, since it includes session.php where it has session_start(). Is it what's causing this?

Comment: `session_start();` must be inside all pages using sessions, plus adding `exit;` after header will stop any further execution. Many times, this fixes it.

Comment: @Fred -ii- just 'exit'? let me try that.

Comment: `header('Location: your_file.php'); exit;` <= yep and for all headers. I said many times, not "always" ;-)

Comment: i still got the same error after putting 'exit' right after the header('Location: ...') lines.

Comment: where do you even use seesion.php?

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of all your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything.
 Also add `or die(mysql_error())` to `mysql_query()`. Make sure you don't have any mod rewrites neither.

Comment: @Escobear: Just edited my post. It's there now, it's included in profile.php.

Comment: on an unrelated note. Dont use mysql database wrapper but mysqli or pdo.

Comment: @ Fred -ii- tried that. same thing. Anyway, here are more details: 
The webpage at login_example/index.php has resulted in too many redirects. Clearing your cookies for this site or allowing third-party cookies may fix the problem. If not, it is possibly a server configuration issue and not a problem with your computer.

Comment: Why do you do this query? `select myUsername from login where myUsername='$user_check'`

Comment: What I think is going on is that your code is erroring out and you're not seeing it, causing it to fight against what it should be showing you as an error. You have `$login_session =$row['username'];` using the `username` as the row, but you're not selecting it in your query `select myUsername from login where myUsername`. So, I'm thinking that if that row doesn't in fact exist, you'd need to do `$login_session =$row['myUsername'];`

Comment: Add to @Fred-ii- 's comment: When you check `isset($login_session)` in session.php. I think what you really want to do is check `empty($login_session)`. isset is always true even if the query returns null.

Comment: @Fred -ii- HOLY YEAH! Thanks man! Yeah I overlooked that part when I edited my code. Thanks a lot! It's working now! ;)

Comment: You're welcome. I posted my answer to close the question.

Comment: @dan08 man, it's (!isset...) i actually have no idea if that works. and yeah, i guess if it works, it's function is pretty much the same as empty().

Anyway, thanks to everyone! I got it working now. :)

Comment: *Phew,* that was a tough one but I'm glad it got resolved, *cheers!*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Comment to answer:*

What I think is going on is that your code is erroring out and you're not seeing it, causing it to fight against what it should be showing you as an error.

You have `$login_session =$row['username'];` using the "username" as the row, but you're not selecting it in your query `select myUsername from login where myUsername`.

So, I'm thinking that if that row doesn't in fact exist, you'd need to do

```
$login_session =$row['myUsername'];
```

Comment: But the query `select myUsername from login where myUsername='$user_check'` will return `$user_check`, won't it?

Comment: @Phate01 Theoretically, it should, yes. If you have any problems, use `var_dump();` to check what's going through (or not).

Comment: So I was thinking that you could skip that and directly use `$user_check`

Comment: @Phate01 Any which way, you'll need to always check if the session is set and used in accordance with the variable. If `$user_check` is used for the session variable, which it is and should be, then that variable being assigned to the session name, should/will populate itself throughout your entire code.

Comment: *Mornin' Ralph* Nailing Jello to trees at the moment, it has been an interesting week @Fred-ii-

Comment: *Mornin' Sam* - That hard huh? Best leave that and fill 'er up with that 20yr old Scotch ;-) @JayBlanchard